# Syntax issue in SQL Server, using OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, openrowset

I am trying to Execute a stored procedure that requires to variables be passing into to it. One is a static, the other is a dynamic variable.

```
DECLARE @Filt DATETIME 
SET @Filt = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Date) FROM Data.db.Staging)
SELECT * INTO #tempData FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=ISR14  \MSSQL2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC GetData.db.Staging @Mode = ''Date'' @Filt ')
```

but that doesn't work, got the error back 
"Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '@Filt'."

I'm guessing it is because Filt is dynamic statement. So I tried this

```
DECLARE @FilterData DATETIME
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200) 
SET @Filt = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(AsOfDate) FROM Data.db.Staging)
SET @sql = 'EXEC GetData.db.Staging @Mode = ''Date'' @Filt =  '  + @Filt

SELECT * INTO #tempData FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=ISR14\MSSQL2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
 @sql)
```

But I get the message back

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near '@sql'."

It seems that OPENROWSET can only accept strings. But I want to pass a variable that is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the whole statement into a variable and run it, and convert @FilterData to a varchar to concatenate it.

You can't use variables with openquery/openrowset.

Try this and check the print output... if it works and looks ok, then EXEC(@sql2)

```
DECLARE @FilterData DATETIME
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200), @sql2 VARCHAR(500)
SET @FilterData = '2014-07-01'--(SELECT DISTINCT MAX(AsOfDate) FROM Data.db.Staging)
SET @sql = 'EXEC GetData.db.Staging @Mode = ''''Date'''', @Filt =  '''''  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@FilterData ,120) + ''''''

SET @sql2 = 'SELECT * INTO #tempData FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=ISR14\MSSQL2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
 '''+@sql+''')'

print @sql2
--exec(@sql2)
```

Comment: That definitely helped! However, I'm now getting this issue:  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '2014'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Comment: Updated, was missing a `,`.  I'm not seeing any un-closed quotation marks though.  Did you get it sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the whole query dynamic, not sure if I got it nailed down, but something like:

```
DECLARE @Filt DATETIME 
       ,@sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Filt = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Data.db.Staging)
SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO #tempData FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=ISR14  \MSSQL2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''EXEC GetData.db.Staging @Mode = ''''Date''' +@Filt+ ')'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: That definitely helped! However, I'm now getting this issue: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '2014'. Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Where 2014 is a part of the MAX date found in @Filt

Comment: @user3259896 Can you show me a string that executes with a hard-coded value instead of the dynamic version? I'm just not sure how `EXEC GetData.db.Staging @Mode = ''''Date''' +@Filt+ ')` should get structured.

Answer (score 0):

I got error Incorrect syntax near '﻿' when executing @sql.
In my case there was invalid character at the beginning of NVARCHAR.
This helped me:

```
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, NCHAR(0xFEFF), '');
```